# Where should I place my middleware file for Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Previously I had my middleware under lib/middleware/my_middle_ware.rb

However when doing this,

```
config.middleware.use MyMiddleWare
```

I receive a

```
NameError: uninitialized constant
```

Where is rails looking for the middleware?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look like rails wasn't looking for it.

I had to do the following for it to work.

```
Dir["./lib/middleware/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

Comment: This is the fix I went with also, but it seems like the framework should be loading these.  Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: @JayP. I agree. Is this a bug? I'm on Rails 5.2 and this is happening. Surprised there's not a standard auto-loaded directory for `middleware`, like there is for `models`, `controllers`, `views`, `mailers`, etc.

Comment: For the record, I dug deep into this and here's the relevant discussion with the Rails Core members about where middleware should go and how to require it: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25525#issuecomment-479941866. In short, _"middleware can't be in app because they can't be reloaded. They should be in lib and if you put them in lib, require_relative will work."_

Answer (score 5):

Create a folder `app/middlewares` and create your middleware file in this folder.

But unfortunately The `app/middleware`s folder is not loading even if I added to the load paths in `Rails v5.2.2`

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/middlewares"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/middlewares"
```

So you can use require explicitly as follows, add this line in `application.rb`

```
require_relative '../app/middlewares/my_middleware'
```

and load middleware:

```
config.middleware.use MyMiddleware
```

and call `rake middleware` to see the middleware stack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to add your middleware to either your `config/application.rb` or your `config/environments` file.

```
config.middleware.use MyMiddleWare
```

This should work and append `MyMiddleWare` to the bottom of the middleware stack.

Answer (score 1):

Even before app/middleware contents are loaded if 'config.middleware.use' is called, I think you get the 'uninitialized Constant error'. The below should fix

```
config.middleware.use "MyMiddleWare"
```

If the above doesn't work, one of the below might be a no.

```
Is MyMiddleWare in app/middleware/my_middle_ware.rb ?

Is MyMiddleWare in lib/my_middle_ware.rb ?
```

Comment: I believe specifying your middleware class using a String was valid only before Rails 5. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25525

Answer (score 0):

replacing middleware as a string in `config/application.rb` to `config/environment/{environment}` as a constant fixed the issue for me